# Test if a WordPress page exists using JavaScript before redirecting to it

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, web-applications, redirect

My link looks like this:

```
 http://localhost:8081/wordpress/?p=535
```

How can I redirect to this page with JavaScript? I'm unfamiliar with the `?` syntax, but I have a feeling I should be able to send some sort of request with the ID of the post?

Something like:

```
redirect("p="+postid);
```

Just calling `window.Location` won't work for me because if the post doesn't exist, then I want to be able to do something else. Also, I don't want it to direct to local host. It needs to direct to the root of the website...

More like this then:

```
if (request("p="+postid) exists) {
    redirect("p="+postid);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
document.location.href = "http://localhost:8081/wordpress/?p=535";
```

If you want to check if the page exists first, you could do this :

```
var addr = "/wordpress/?p=535"; // here with a relative url
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: addr,
    success: function() {
        document.location.href = addr;
    }
});
```

This will make a HEAD request (so no content download) to check if the page exists and only change the current location if it's OK.

*Note that you may do that without jQuery if you want, I let you determine the exact syntax if needed.*

But this can only work if both page are from the same domain.

Comment: ^That is fine, I can use jQuery. So, @dystroy this helps a litle more. My next problem is removing the necesisty for "localhost" - How can I make it so that it is just like "/wordpress/?p=" + pid; URLs should really never be hard coded!

Comment: I don't think this will work because he's not looking for a random page, but rather for a random post-ID. Since all that's changing is the query string the server-side framework supporting the posts probably won't return an HTTP 404, but rather a normal page (300 OK) that has an error message for the user saying that the post doesn't exist.

Comment: You can do relative URL if you want, even protocol relative one : http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: I haven't looked into this—but is that true in practice?

Comment: @DaoWen If I make the Ajax request and it is not a 404, I did something similar once in C#. I sent an HTTP request, got the response, and searched for a formatted tag in the response for me to be able to determine if the page existed (I searched for "This page does not exist" kind of) - Is there a way to do this with JS?

Comment: @dystroy settles that then, makes my life easier. I am going to upvote all of you now! Thanks!!

Comment: @dystroy - Wordpress uses something like mod_rewrite to make URLs with actual paths for each post. If all you're changing is the query string then I would actually thing it's strange for one query string to return a 300 OK and the other to return a 404 Not Found. I think the answer here is that good frameworks don't use the query string!

Comment: @DaoWen check the HTTP header of an answer to [this query](http://canop.org/blog/?p=443333) : it's a 404 code even while there is a content in the body

Comment: @dystroy you are so helpful, I have a lot of trouble understanding the difference between Ajax and Http.

Comment: HTTP is the protocol over which queries are made from a browser to a server. [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is both a set of practices aiming at not replacing synchronously the window content and the name of a jquery function commonly used for this (that's the best explanation I can make in comment...).

Comment: @dystroy - Weird, you're right. My point wasn't whether or not there was content in the body, but rather whether or not there were valid pages at the same path with a different query string. That example shows a framework where different query strings at the same path will yield a 404. (On a side note, I just realized everywhere I said 300 OK above should have been 200 OK.)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:8081/wordpress/?p=535";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = "http://localhost:8081/wordpress/?p=535";
```

UPDATE:- after the comment
althought this aint the trick that should be used but can be
try sending an ajax request to the url and if it successfull returns some content redirect else if there is an `404` error just do something else.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is another way, although this works. Like, I used to perform ajax requests. I need to do a little more than redirect, meaning, if the post doesn't exist, I want to do something else.

Comment: @user1274649 - If that's the case 1) you should have said so in your question and 2) you probably need to do this server-side rather than client-side using JavaScript.

Comment: you can't detect if a URL is valid or not on the client-side.

Comment: @Philipp you can. See my answer.

Comment: @DaoWen Yeah I might post another question then. I'm not good at wording what I need to do. This place needs to be less condescending really, I don't pay you all to help me or for anyone to volunteer. I'm always met with help but also people who complain about the way I word my question. You all do realize that I can just post another question if the question I'm asking doesn't adequately express what I want...its not a big deal!

Comment: @user1274649 - Maybe the issue is with you -- you do realize you are getting expert help for free.  Act like you care what we think and you might just see people treat you with respect in return.

Comment: @Hogan I realize this. I also realize it takes 0 effort to come on here and post a question and get help. It's not like it will run out. It's not like it's a huge deal, and on top of that, It's not like I've never helped anyone in my life (Just not on SO, not experienced enough yet I think.) I think part of the learning process is learning how to ask questions. Does this mean I should get an attitude every time I make a mistake? I don't think so. I think if you're going to come on here and help people, learn how people work. Meaning: Don't be a dick to people. I will care when people are nice.

Comment: @Hogan I also am a very sensitive person, I'm female, and I have trouble expressing technical thoughts. I'm working on it though. Of course I appreciate that people here help me. But it's not like if I make 1 mistake I'll never be helped again. Thats what i think people need to realize. People make mistakes, be nice about it. That way they care more. Everyone wins.

Comment: @user1274649 - As you can see from my rep, I've answered a lot of questions on SO.  I can honestly say, it is much harder to do as you ask than know the answers -- you've already said knowing the answers is hard.   Consider this possibility -- people were *REALLY* nice to you.  They tried to answer your question.  You said... oh no that does not help at all because I really meant something else.  If you had said "Thanks for your help, but seeing the answers made me realize I was wrong in my question... I also need ..."  You see the difference?

Comment: @user1274649 - To be honest it took me a few months to get the hang of SO -- don't worry, you will get the hang of it.  But I don't think people were close to mean to you on this question they gave you all the answers you needed in just a few minutes.  You responded mostly grumpy.  Maybe a cup of coffee will perk you up and put you in a good mood?

Comment: @Hogan I see what you're saying! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I'll get the hang of it eventually, hopefully. I'm going to be in tech my whole life and honestly SO Is great!! People help me all the time. I'm not even sure why they do! How is it possible 6 or 7 people respond with the same answer? I feel like There should be some way for SO to process this so that, not everyone wastes their time posting the same answer. You're right, people were really nice. But thats also because my question was so simple, that it required a simple answer! Coffee sounds great, :)

Comment: @user1274649 - SO is great.  I recommend you check out the meta link and the blog link for some insight into the "some way for SO to process..." question (or to offer suggestions if you have them on meta.)  Years from now when you are answering questions you might have insight as to why... I'd say part of being a accomplished technology practitioner is being open to learning and sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable post ID into the location like this:

```
var postID = 535;
window.location = "http://localhost:8081/wordpress/?p="+postID;
```

---

Now that you've updated your question I think it's obvious that this isn't a job for JavaScript. If you want to check if a page exists you should be doing that check server-side since only the server-side code has access to your database where it can check if specific post IDs actually exist or not.

You could of course code up some AJAX interface where the JavaScript goes off and makes a query to the server-side code to see if the post exists, and then you'll get your answer back and act on it accordingly—but that seems really over-complicated for this problem.

Comment: It does sound like a round about way to do it, HOWEVER, what if the post ID exists, yet the page is "disabled"....maybe I can do that check instead.

Answer (score 0):

To send the user to another URL, use

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8081/wordpress/?p=535'
```

The stuff after "?" is part of the URL and is meant to be processed by a server-sided program.

Comment: thanks! What's the difference between having a ? and a & - I've used both for ajax requests - do you know?